# Eureka multiple defaultZone, CloudConfig and @Value annotation

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config, service-discovery

I'm using **Spring Boot 2.4.4** and **spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client 3.0.2**.

Inside my code I use some **@Value** and **@ConfigurationProperties**, without providing default values, to bind properties and methods from a configuration file that has to be retrieved from the ConfigServer.

In the following picture a representation of my instances.

[image]

I register two instances of Eureka Server (**spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server 3.0.2**), one on port 8081 and the other on port 8082.

My *MyMicroService*'s bootstrap contains both urls as *defaultZone*, point is that **whenever the first Eureka is up** and running everything works fine: both of the Eureka show that the microservice is registered, the ms is able to recover the configuration from the *ConfigServer* (also retrieved from Eureka). **When the first Eureka is down**, the microservice tries to connect to it then fail and an ERROR is raised since it wans't able to resolve a placeholder (inside a @Value annotation) then stops without trying the other Eureka url (8082).

[image]

I find it strange that it tries to start up the microservice before trying all the Eureka defaultZone URLs. Am I missing something?

Also, I can't give default values to those properties and in another microservice, without annotations, it works, it tries to connect to 8081, fails and then tries 8082.

Is there a configuration that specify to try all defaultZone before trying to evaluate @Value and @ConfigurationProperties annotations?